# Looping through elements in an array and displaying in each cardView

Tags: android, loops, for-loop

I'm using a cardView to display data, there are a total of 5 cards and in each I want a different card name.

The name is to be displayed beside each cardView. I'm using a loop to iterate all the names like this:

```
String [] cardNames = {"a", "b", " c", "d"," e"};
String cardName = null;

for(int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++){
      cardName = cardNames[i];
}
```

The loop to display each card name looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++;){
      "Item" + (i + 1) + cardName;
}
```

Instead what I get is the all the cardViews with the same name i.e

```
Item 1    //cardName e
Item 2    //cardName e
// and so on
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Code posted is not sufficient for diagnosis. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Of course, when you end your first cycle cardName get 1 value, and in the second cycle you assign that value to every card

Comment: Did you used listview or recylerview to showing cards means recyclerView item is your cardview like this or Jusr simply put all  5 cards in Linear
Layout ???

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this

```
    String [] cardNames = {"a", "b", " c", "d"," e"};
    String cardName = null;
            for(int i=0;i<cardNames.length;i++){
               cardName = cardNames[i];
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                     System.out.println("Item" + (j + 1) + cardName);
                 }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do everything in one loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++){
  cardName = cardNames[i];
  String display = "Item " + (i + 1) + " " + cardName;
  view.setText(display);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an ArrayList object for cardName and while iterating the loop add the `cardNames[i]` to the `cardName` ArrayList.

```
String [] cardNames = {"a", "b", " c", "d"," e"};
ArrayList<String> cardName = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++){
      cardName.add(cardNames[i]);
}
```

and you can retrieve it -

```
for(int i = 0; i < cardName.size(); i++;){
      "Item" + (i + 1) + cardName.get(i);
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You have single variable for keeping card names i.e. cardName.

By the looks of your code you are trying to save cardName by looping through cardNames array then looping again for displaying card.

Since you have single variable for saving card name, your cardName variable will contain value of last card name i.e. cardName e.

Easiest way to get your output would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++;){
  "Item" + (i + 1) + cardNames[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you, if not then please explain your query.

```
String [] cardNames = {"a", "b", " c", "d"," e"};
String cardName = null;

for(int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++){
     "Item" + (i + 1) +  cardNames[i];
}
```